# Detect Multiple Custom HTML-5 Attributes on Same Page - Adobe DTM

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics, tms

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to detect multiple custom HTML-5 attributes (i.e. "data-analytics-exp-name") and aggregate their values (with a delimiter) into a cookie using Adobe DTM without the user being involved (attributes only need to exist on the page and not be clicked on etc.).

I currently have a rule that reads a single custom HTML-5 attribute and performs
 what I want using an event type of "element exists" and using:

```
    var currExpName = this.getAttribute('data-analytics-exp-name');
```

but not sure how to approach for multiples at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to get all attributes on the page, you will want to use something that can access the whole page. Try the following code:

`document.querySelectorAll("[data-analytics-exp-name]");

This should return all DOM elements containing the attribute `data-analytics-exp-name`. From there you can parse the array however you'd like to get the concatenated string you're looking for.